# how to replace &,?,.,= to another string and redirect this to file?

Tags: mod-rewrite

What do I have to do to replace

```
& = [and]
? = [vop]
. = [too]
= = [rav]
```

from URI using mod_rewrite?

For example I need to redirect:

```
"http://www.domain.com/?boo=1" to "http://www.domain.com/[vop]boo[rav]1"
"http://www.domain.com/page?puhovoi=3" to "http://www.domain.com/page[vop]puhovoi[rav]3"
"http://www.domain.com/iphone/iphone.asp?model=3&big=43" to "http://www.domain.com/iphone/iphone[too]asp[vop]model[rav]3[and]big[rav]43"
```

etc., also directories, query parametres and so on may be absolutely different. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345314/apache-mod-rewrite-replace-character-with-another). You can write a similar RewriteRule. The problem is, if you don't know exact order of the replacing character, you'll gona be stuckt. IMHO their is no way to do search and replace with mod_rewrite.

Comment: yeah it's solved with redirecting to php script and parsing query string, but thanks anyway